# Confused with def main()

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm relatively new to Python, so I'm not sure how to approach this. I don't expect you to show code, just trying to learn more about best practices in Python. I've been trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://realpython.com/python-main-function/) but still slightly confused.

So, let's say I have a collection of .csv files in a folder; say in the following path : ("D:/Files/"). All the .csv files have just two columns: 'A' and 'B'. I want to create two new columns using the following criterion: multiply each row in column 'A' by 2, and multiply each row in column 'B' by 5. I then want to create a third row which displays the sum of these two new rows I've created. The final output is the dataframe saved to a new .csv file, with the final column (and 2 original columns).

I'm trying to code this in such a way as to import it in a module in a different script as well, so I can then run it on multiple files in a folder. I approach coding it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

def multiply_by_3(df):
    A = df['A']
    new_column_1 = [elem*2 for elem in A]
    return new_column_1

def multiply_by_5(df):
    B = df['B']
    new_column_2 = [elem*5 for elem in B]
    return new_column_2

def find_sum(new_column_1,new_column_2):
    C = [sum(x) for x in zip(new_column_1, new_column_2)]
    return C

##Attempt at main function
def main():
    new_column_1    = multiply_by_3()
    new_column_2    = multiply_by_5()
    sum_of_new_cols = find_sum(new_column_1,new_column_2)
```

Here's where I'm lost:

1. How do I add the new column to the dataframe? When I add df['new_column'] = sum_of_new_cols to the script, it doesn't compile as df is not defined.
2. I'm not sure how to approach that last "main" function in such a way that I can save it as a module that I can call in a separate script, which will allow me to apply these functions to multiple files in one go.
3. I can import other scripts as modules, and use specific functions within a module (e.g. multiply_by_5), but how would I run the whole script (i.e. all the functions) where there is a "main" function? The tutorial I linked to says the benefit of using a "main" function is that it runs all the previous functions before it.

Any links to relevant resources would be appreciated, as I realise this is probably a really dumb question.

Comment: You need to create the dataframe in `main()`, and then pass it as an argument when you call `multiply_by_3()` and `multiply_by_5()`.

Comment: The code you've written shouldn't even run because you're nor providing the arguments to those functions.

Comment: Where is your code that creates `df` from the CSV files?

Comment: @Barmar that makes a lot more sense - the code doesn't run in it's current format. The idea was to be able to import this script into a module, and import the dataframes from multiple files in the second script (using pd.read_csv). Does that mean I have to create the "main" function in the second script instead?

Comment: Yes, you should define a different function here, and it should take `df` as a parameter, and call that from the main function in the other script.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you - that makes a lot of sense.